# Not passing into function with a switch case

Tags: php, validation, smarty

I currently have this setup:

```
class Post_Validations {
        protected $mysqli;
        protected $URI;
        public $_POST;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->_SQL = new mysqli("");
            $this->URI = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        public function Register(){
            print_r($this->_POST);
        }
        public function RenderForms($FormID){


    switch ((int)$FormID){
            case 192:
                $this->Register();
                echo "Register Form";
                break;
            default:
                echo "NOT FOUND";
        }
    }


}
```

with;

```
   $Test = new Smarty_Views();
        if (isset($_POST)){
        if (in_array("FormID",$params)){
            $FormSearch = array_search("FormID",$params);
        }
        $Form = new Post_Validations;
        foreach ($params AS $Keys => $Values){
            if ($Values === "FormID"){
                $Form->RenderForms($params[$Keys++]);
                echo $params[$Keys++];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
$Test->Display_Page($params[0]);
```

I'm getting this display: [image: Not passing]

With the correct case with explicit type juggling, it's displaying the "default" option with the Switch function, i cannot see where i'm going wrong, so i'm wondering if someone can spot the problem and explain why?

---

New Update:

The new Index page: http://pastebin.com/kjPY7bFf

The new Libs.inc.php: http://pastebin.com/YQzWVqSW

The New Post.Valid.php: http://pastebin.com/5wFbjSqu

With all this being updated, I can sucessfully say I do reach:

```
$FormValidation->FormID($Parameters[$Form_Key]);
```

Which this method is set to echo out the FormID which is passed first, which outputs at **192**

The if statement in FormID is set to echo out "yay" if FormID is equal to 192, which judging by the echo, it is

Comment: try to change `$Keys++` just to `$Keys`

Comment: @IlyaBursov The current set of $Keys will contain the key which contains the value of `FormID` so adding 1  to this index will pass the form id

Comment: I'm lost with your logic, anyway you cannot increment it, as it used in foreach statement, and it is not the same as for statement

Comment: and why the second increment on keys ? I'm talking about this line:  `echo $params[$Keys++];`

Comment: @IlyaBursov If "FormID" is found, +1 to the keys current index and pass it into the function and break the foreach to stop other iterations

Comment: @Raiyan This is just to show the value which is being passed into the form for debugging purposes

Comment: @SophieMackeral this will not work, it is not for statement

Comment: @IlyaBursov Care to share

Comment: @SophieMackeral you're increment value twice, this is obviously wrong, even one increment is wrong here, you can try `$Keys+1`, but I still do not understand the overall logic of your approach and cannot tell if it will work

Comment: @IlyaBursov Output is what I want it to be! I'm getting the output of `192` which is the figure i'm passing into the method of the secondary RenderForm... It's not calling the method located in the switch!

Comment: @SophieMackeral no, you're not passing 192 to RenderForms, you're passing some value (which maybe string or number), which can be different from time to time too, with added 1 to it, this is not how it will work, and I suppose I will not be able to help you, as you do not understand your code at all :(

Comment: @IlyaBursov i've just spent this time rewritting the entire structure, and can confirm I am infact passing `192` into the method. I will update with my new structure

Comment: @SophieMackeral change your code to `echo "NOT FOUND [".$FormID.']';` and you will see what value(s) you're passing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40988/discussion-between-sophie-mackeral-and-ilya-bursov)